# A client reported a html5 video playback error in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I've been trying to verify whether or not a report from a client that on IE9 the video on the homepage is showing with 2 black bars one at the top and one at the bottom.

I've googled a fix, but being a Mac user and not having IE9 handy I cannot verify it.

I'm wondering if anyone can look up the url and verify if the problem is indeed true and even better if you've stumbled across this before and perhaps know a fix.

URL: http://yellowtulipcomms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ha ha, I LOVE this question.  I had to repartition my old laptop and install another copy of windows yesterday just to get a glimpse in IE9, as I am trying to find a solution for this myself.

Yes, black lines are confirmed.

IE9 must have an aspect ratio issue?

CSS "background-color:#fffff;" would have solved this for me (and you) but that didn't seem to have any affect.

IE9 just wouldn't be IE without throwing a few curveballs at us, now would it?
My hat is off to the IE people for finally following most of the rules in IE9 though.

My poor-man's solution was to disable HTML5 video for IE9 by using IE conditional tags around the video element, only revealing my flash (flowplayer) fallback solution to IE9.
If anyone has a prettier solution though I'd love to do that instead, thanks!

```
<!--[if !(IE 9) ]><!-->
<video width="647" height="363" autoplay>
    <source src="video/home/movie.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"'>
    <source src="video/home/movie.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora"'>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <div class="flash-fallback">
        <a href="video/home/movie.m4v" alt="Download Video"></a>
    </div>
<!--[if !(IE 9) ]><!-->
</video>
<!--<![endif]-->
```